# How to generate all ASCII characters with a brace expansion?

Tags: bash

This lists all English characters:

```
$ echo {A..Z}
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

But how to list all ASCII characters?

I tried this:

```
$ echo {\!..\~}
{!..~}
```

and this:

```
$ echo {$'!'..$'~'}
{!..~}
```

But both did not work. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't; the range operator only works with letters and numbers.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion

Comment: @melpomene It uses just the word "character" but not "alphabetic character".

Comment: Hmm. Fair enough.

Comment: Note that listing _all_ ASCII characters is not a good idea as the lower ones are control characters and will mess with your terminal emulator. I would start with 32.

Comment: @ceving There are implications, though, that "character" implies alphabetic character. At the very least, the man page distinguishes between numeric characters and others: "Note that both x and y must be of the same type.", which precludes something like `{9..A}`.

Comment: See the definition of `expand_seqterm` in `braces.c` in the `bash` source code; it explicitly checks for alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses only one `printf` but a more complicated brace expansion.

```
printf '%b' \\x{0..7}{{0..9},{a..f}}
```

It also works, but not as nicely (it outputs a lot of whitespace):

```
echo -e \\x{0..7}{{0..9},{a..f}}
```

Comment: So `{!..~}` would be `printf '%b\n' \\x2{{1..9},{a..f}} \\x{3..6}{{0..9},{a..f}} \\x7{{1..9},{a..e}}`-

Answer (score 2):

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(printf '\%03o' {0..127})"



123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

To see a representation of the non-printable characters in the output from the above and the characters hidden by the effect of trying to print them as-is, you can pipe it to `cat -v`:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(printf '\%03o' {0..127})" | cat -v
^@^A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H
^K^L^M^N^O^P^Q^R^S^T^U^V^W^X^Y^Z^[^\^]^^^_ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~^?
```

To print just from the ASCII code for `!` (33) to the ASCII code for `~` (126):

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(printf '\%03o' {33..126})"
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

and to print from `!` to `~` without having to know their numeric values:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(eval printf '\\%03o' $(printf '{%d..%d}' "'!" "'~"))"
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

which you can use with shell variables to hold the beginning and ending chars:

```
$ beg='!'; end='~';
$ printf '%b\n' "$(eval printf '\\%03o' $(printf '{%d..%d}' "'$beg" "'$end"))"
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```